# Geolocation error in android

Tags: android, geolocation

here is the code below

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
        alert("ok");

       // var options = { timeout: 0, maximumAge: 600000 };
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError);

    }
function onSuccess(position) {
    alert("success");
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;

}
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
           'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

It works in all browsers , iphone and WindowsPhone. But in andorid in gives me error code :3 timeout expired error.

I enabled gps, wi-fi also in the settings menu--> location services -->location and Google Search,
In the browser menu settings--> privacy and settings enable location is checked.

What is the problem , any ideas? i really stuck in.

Answer (score -1):

Normally , we accept the website request that wants to share your location.

In android if you do not see the question then in the browser settings `advanced--> website settings` add your URL to there.

It solves the problem.